# Making the content inside grid items equal height in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I am trying to figure out how to get two columns of my grid the same height. Here is what I am after:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 

x qqqqqqqqqqqqq x    x qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq x 

x qqqqqqqqqqqqq x    x qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq x 

x               x    x qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq x 

x               x    x qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq x 

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This is where the x's represent a border of a grid (display: grid) and the q's are labels and input fields.
Here is all the code and a link to the same on codepen.

```
.container {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}

.outerGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 1fr 30px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "title title title title" 
    ". companyInfo contactInfo . "
    ". demoInfo demoInfo . " 
    "footer footer footer footer";
}

.companyInfoContainer {
  grid-area: companyInfo;
}

.companyInfoBox {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}

.contactInfoContainer {
    grid-area: contactInfo;
}

.contactInfoBox {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas: 'contactLeft contactRight';
    border: 1px solid #666;
    padding: 20px;
}

.titleRow {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.formControl {
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    display: block;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-image: none;
}

.formTitleTop {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.formTitle {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

...and the html:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="outerGrid">
    <div class="companyInfoContainer">
      <div class="titleRow">
        <div>Company Information</div>
        <div>* Required</div>
      </div>
      <div class="companyInfoBox">
        <div class="formTitleTop">Company Name*</div><input type="text" class="formControl" value="">
        <div class="formTitle">Website (leave blank if not website)</div>
        <input type="text" class="formControl" value=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="contactInfoContainer">
      <div class="titleRow">
        <div>Contact Information</div>
        <div class="required">* Required</div>
      </div>
      <div class="contactInfoBox">
        <div class="contactLeft">
          <div class="formTitleTop">First Name*</div><input type="text" class="formControl" value="">
          <div class="formTitle">Last Name*</div><input type="text" class="formControl" value="">
          <div class="formTitle">Role*</div><input type="text" class="formControl" value=""><input type="button" value="Add Additional Contacts"></div>
        <div class="contactRight">
          <div class="formTitleTop">Phone Number*</div><input type="text" class="formControl" value="">
          <div class="formTitle">Mobile Phone Number</div><input type="text" class="formControl" value="">
          <div class="formTitle">Email Address*</div><input type="text" class="formControl" value=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/GuitarJ/pen/QqZRYR

I can't seem to get the left column to stretch to the height of the right col's height (which I think is the row height too. I was hoping that css grids would have a way to do this, but its hard to search for this exact issue.

I also tried setting the height to 100%, but then it didn't respect the grid-gap and went down too far.

How can I make the left side be the row height?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those grid items are already the same height. They are both the height of the second row, which is `1fr`, as defined by `grid-template-rows` on the grid container.

If you put a border around those two items (`.companyInfoContainer` & `.contactInfoContainer`), you'll see what I mean.

[revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGJwLw)

It seems that you want the bordered children of the grid items (`.companyInfoBox` and `.contactInfoBox`) to consume all available height.

Since the grid items are not also grid containers, [you can't use grid properties on the children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46800525/3597276).

An **easy and efficient solution** would be to make the grid items flex containers. Then you can apply flex properties to the children, which can make them consume free space.

```
.companyInfoContainer {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.companyInfoBox {
   flex: 1;
 }

.contactInfoContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contactInfoBox {
   flex: 1
}
```

[revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMPEmB)

More details: [Descendant element not responding to grid properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46800525/3597276)

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm! Seems I was not thinking about it correctly, you are right though, I was thinking the child boxes were top level in the grid which they clearly are not. Once I understood that, it all made sense!

Answer (score 0):

use `display` property `flex`  with item height `auto`

for example

```
.flex-container {
display: flex;
width: 400px;
height: auto;
```

}

```
.flex-item {
background: red;
width: 100px;
height: auto;
margin: 10px;
```

}

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I added a full layout sample with codepen link, so maybe that will help.

Comment: I guess I got it what you r looking for you can go with this approach using flex.
https://codepen.io/saurabhsharma722/pen/oGQqBp

Comment: I want to stick with display: grid. I can always set the height the way @dantethesmith stated, but I was hoping for a much less manual way. If I have dynamic rows, that would not work...

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the same size if grid doesn't change (you don't insert new elements dynamically or change existing ones vertical size)

```
.companyInfoBox {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    height: 265px;
}
```

It's simple and works (taking into accounts restrictions listed above):
[pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bomPYG)