# Overflow/Extend CSS Grid-Areas for Certain Elements

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm learning CSS Grid and am very fascinated by it. Particularly, I'm using the `template-areas` approach to define structure. Here's an example of the code I have written to define a basic article layout with two sidebars, a main content area, and an article footer:

HTML:

```
<div class="article-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-left">
    Left Sidebar Content
    </div>
    <div class="article-content">
        Main Article Content
        <div class="article-overflow">
            Overflow Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-right">
        Right Sidebar Content
    </div>
    <div class="article-footer">
        Article Footer Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.article-wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-areas:
          "h h h h h h h h h h h h"
          "l l c c c c c c c c r r"
          "l l f f f f f f f f r r";
}

.article-wrapper > .article-sidebar-left{
  grid-area: l;
}
.article-wrapper > .article-sidebar-right{
  grid-area: r;
}
.article-wrapper > .article-content{
  grid-area: c;
}
.article-wrapper > .article-footer{
  grid-area: f;
}
```

My question; is there a way, using this approach of grid areas, that I can make the `article-overflow` element, which is wholly within the `c` `grid-template-area` to extend into the `l` and `r` areas?

Essentially, I'd like the width of the `article-overflow` element to be as such:

`l x x x x x x x x x x x r` whereas now it is `l l x x x x x x x x r r`

In other words, I'm trying to extend it one grid unit into each of the areas used by the sidebars currently.

Answer (score 1):

> ...is there a way, using this approach of grid areas, that I can make the `.article-overflow` element, which is wholly within the `c` grid-template-area to extend into the `l` and `r` areas?

No.

The `.article-overflow` element isn't even a grid item, so it doesn't recognize grid properties<sup>1</sup>.

There's a possibility that in a future version of Grid Layout the `subgrid` feature <sup>2</sup>, which allows the children of grid items to respect the lines of the primary container, will be implemented. But that's speculation. And even then, there's no guarantee that the grid area you want will be available with `grid-template-areas`. It may only be available with *line-based placement* <sup>3</sup>.

---

Notes:

<sup>1</sup> [Grid properties not working on elements inside grid container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46800525/3597276)

<sup>2</sup> [Positioning content of grid items in primary container (subgrid feature)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929369/3597276)

<sup>3</sup> [Line-based placement with CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Line-based_Placement_with_CSS_Grid)

Comment: For the record, the CSSWG has already asserted that line names _will_ be inherited.