# How can I properly align my opening times in my grid?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I made a Codepen: https://codepen.io/coder_extends_human/pen/eLLmgb

So I made a layout consisting of 12 tracks. I floated the exact times of the opening times to the right so it looks fine. I want the opening times to align with the "IMPRESSUM" but the way I did it it doesn't work. I tried to add min-content and max-content to the track including the opening times but it still gets fucked. CSS grid is still very confusing to although I already worked on this issue for 4 hours :(

Thanks in advance

```
.main {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46800525/3597276

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't one of Grid; your "Opening Times" and all the times themselves are in a single container element (`<section class=five>`), and it's that container that's the grid item. The container spans 3 columns (and by the way, you want to remove the explicit `width` on the `section`, it's making your element overflow the columns), and the contents then just format normally; they don't care about the outer grid.

So, use ordinary block layout mechanisms. Make the "Opening Times" element a normal block (right now it's being set to `inline-block`) and use `text-align: right` on it, as @Batajus suggests.

Using the Dev Tools on your browser should show these facts, and the sizes and positions of your elements, fairly clearly; both Chrome and Firefox will show the grid lines of a grid container (so you can tell that your "Opening Times" element isn't aligning to them in any way).

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I understand your question right and you wanted to text "Opening times" to be aligned with the text "Impressum".

You can do following to get it:

```
.f3 {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%; // Set the width to the width of the parent
}
```