# Make a grid area span two rows

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

This is a very peculiar situation I have never seen before. The first image is my mock-up from Adobe XD and the second is a screenshot of my site from Google Chrome, which shows how the grid is being interpreted by the browser.

As you can see, I have two nav elements: a "sub nav," which provides organizational links; and a "main nav," which provides site links. The CSS id/class naming convention follows, such that:

*#header__main-nav* and #header__sub-nav are the nav HTML elements;
*#main-nav__container* and #sub-nav__container are the ul HTML elements;
.main-nav__item and .sub-nav__item are the li elements; and
.main-nav__link and .sub-nav__link are the anchor tags.

I created a grid with ten columns and two rows. The logo, which is intentionally placed to "overflow" out of its parent 'header' element, is to take up an entire first column and the other eight columns are to be split into two rows, each with a nav element. As you can see from the grid outlines, however, that is not happening. The logo is spanning one row of the first column, sharing it with sub-nav and main-nav is in a second row beneath the logo.

Mockup:

[image: Mockup]

Sub-nav highlighted, showing first row size:

[image: Sub-nav highlighted, showing first row size]

Main-nav highlighted, showing second row size and excluding "grid-area: logo":

[image: Main-nav highlighted, showing second row size and excluding "grid-area: logo"]

The CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1101px) {

    /* Mobile-specific style for floating elements left */
    .mobile-only-style {
        float: left;
    }

    /* Grid/Float Declarations */
    #grid__main {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 2vw;
    }

    body {
        font-size: calc(1.5vw + 0.5em);
    }

    #grid__wrapper {
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
    }

    /* Header Styles */
    header#grid__header {
        height: 9vw;
        z-index: 1;
        margin: 0;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: (10, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: (2, 1fr);
        grid-template-areas:
            "logo logo . . . sub-nav sub-nav sub-nav sub-nav sub-nav"
            "logo logo . . main-nav main-nav main-nav main-nav main-nav main-nav"
    }

    img#header__logo {
        grid-area: logo;
        width: 15vw;
        height: auto;
        margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
        padding: 0;
    }

    /* Navigation Styles */

    /* Main Nav */
    nav#header__main-nav {
        grid-area: main-nav;
        width: calc(75vw - 1em);
        height: 50%;
    }

    ul#main-nav__container {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        margin: 0;
    }

    li.main-nav__item {
        height: 50%;
    }

    li a.main-nav__link {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: calc(.8vw + 0.6em);
        font-family: atrament-web, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant-caps: all-petite-caps;
        color: white;
        -webkit-text-decoration-line: underline;
        text-decoration-line: underline;
        -webkit-text-decoration-color: var(--brand-color);
        text-decoration-color: var(--brand-color);
        -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        transition: all 1s;
    }

    li a#main-nav__link-active {
        color: white;
        font-size: scale(1.2);
        -webkit-text-decoration-line: none;
        text-decoration-line: none;
        -webkit-text-decoration-color: none;
        text-decoration-color: none;
    }

    /* Sub-nav */

    nav#header__sub-nav {
        grid-area: sub-nav;
        height: auto;
        width: calc(75vw - 1em);
        height: 25%;
    }

    ul#sub-nav__container {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0;
    }

    li.sub-nav__item {
        height: 25%;
    }

    li a.sub-nav__link {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: calc(.5vw + 0.3em);
        font-family: atrament-web, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: white;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        transition: all 1s;
    }

    li a#sub-nav__link-active {
        color: white;
        font-size: scale(1.2);
        -webkit-text-decoration-line: none;
        text-decoration-line: none;
        -webkit-text-decoration-color: none;
        text-decoration-color: none;
    }
[...]
}
```

I tried being more specific with my column sizes and adding a third row, which is to be occupied by only the logo in the first column. Same result--no change.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1101px) {

    /* Mobile-specific style for floating elements left */
    .mobile-only-style {
        float: left;
    }

    /* Grid/Float Declarations */
    #grid__main {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 2vw;
    }

    body {
        font-size: calc(1.5vw + 0.5em);
    }

    #grid__wrapper {
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
    }

    /* Header Styles */
    header#grid__header {
        height: 9vw;
        z-index: 1;
        margin: 0;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr, 1fr, 6fr, 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: (3, 1fr);
        grid-template-areas:
            "logo . sub-nav ."
            "logo main-nav main-nav main-nav"
            "logo . . ."
    }

    img#header__logo {
        grid-area: logo;
        width: 15vw;
        height: auto;
        margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
        padding: 0;
    }

    /* Navigation Styles */

    /* Main Nav */
    nav#header__main-nav {
        grid-area: main-nav;
        width: calc(75vw - 1em);
        height: 50%;
    }

    ul#main-nav__container {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        margin: 0;
    }

    li.main-nav__item {
        height: 50%;
    }

    li a.main-nav__link {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: calc(.8vw + 0.6em);
        font-family: atrament-web, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant-caps: all-petite-caps;
        color: white;
        -webkit-text-decoration-line: underline;
        text-decoration-line: underline;
        -webkit-text-decoration-color: var(--brand-color);
        text-decoration-color: var(--brand-color);
        -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        transition: all 1s;
    }

    li a#main-nav__link-active {
        color: white;
        font-size: scale(1.2);
        -webkit-text-decoration-line: none;
        text-decoration-line: none;
        -webkit-text-decoration-color: none;
        text-decoration-color: none;
    }

    /* Sub-nav */

    nav#header__sub-nav {
        grid-area: sub-nav;
        height: auto;
        width: calc(75vw - 1em);
        height: 25%;
    }

    ul#sub-nav__container {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0;
    }

    li.sub-nav__item {
        height: 25%;
    }

    li a.sub-nav__link {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: calc(.5vw + 0.3em);
        font-family: atrament-web, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: white;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        transition: all 1s;
    }

    li a#sub-nav__link-active {
        color: white;
        font-size: scale(1.2);
        -webkit-text-decoration-line: none;
        text-decoration-line: none;
        -webkit-text-decoration-color: none;
        text-decoration-color: none;
    }
```

Comment: `grid-template-columns: (10, 1fr);` is invalid. Maybe `grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);`?

Comment: Tried that. No go.

Comment: In fact, now the main-nav is stuck in the first column of the second row. http://www.tottm.org/test/

Comment: can you also share a mockup of what you would like to see as the final correct result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You need to move `grid-area: logo` from `img#header__logo` to the `a` parent.

---

### Explanation

You have a misconception about how Grid works, or a coding error, depending on how you see it.

This is your grid HTML:

[image]

There are four grid items.

Here's the CSS for the container:

```
header#grid__header {
    height: 9vw;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: calc(15vw + 1em) 9fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-template-areas: "logo sub-nav" 
                         "logo main-nav";
}
```

Looks good. The logo is set to span two rows.

The `sub-nav` grid area is defined correctly:

```
nav#header__sub-nav {
    grid-area: sub-nav;
    height: auto;
    width: calc(75vw - 1em);
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The `main-nav` grid area is defined correctly:

```
nav#header__main-nav {
    grid-area: main-nav;
    width: calc(75vw - 1em);
    height: auto;
}
```

However, **your logo grid area is missing**.

[image]

Actually, you've defined the `logo` grid area on the child of the grid item:

[image]

Because the grid area is applied to the child of a grid item, it is [**out of scope**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46800525/3597276) and the rule is ignored. Move the rule to the parent, where it can be seen by the grid container.

Comment: Ok, that's getting us somewhere because neither I nor my professor could figure it out. What she was able to decipher, so to speak, was that if you removed the anchor tag, the grid worked fine. If you, however, added the anchor tag, the grid broke.

So, are you saying that, because the img is a child of <a>, the 
<a> tag needs to be assigned the grid-area name?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the "out of scope" reference I posted. It provides a full explanation.

Comment: I didn't realize <a> elements take their children out of scope because they aren't block-level elements. One of the things that was driving me nuts was that, for Chrome, Safari, AND Firefox, the responsive design modes were rendering the sites correctly. It was not until I uploaded the styles to the server that the issue appeared.

Comment: While you're around, for stackoverflow economy and since you're incredibly awesome, can you help me once more?

Everything that is not the header (containing the logo and nav bars) or the footer, including the "widgets" panel, is in the main element. The primary content is inside an article with the id "#main__primary-content__container". It is supposed to have a background color of var(--main-content). Alas, it disappeared when trying to do a clearfix on it. 

I have tried everything to get it back. 

[http:.//www.tottm.org] (http://www.tottm.org)

Comment: Not on a pc right now. Will come back to you probably tomorrow.

Comment: Awesome man. I really appreciate this... I'm a monster with JS, but for some reason the intricacies of CSS have always eluded me. ;P

Comment: Just as an FYI--I was able to extend color to the article by applying color to the body element. As the code otherwise indicates, it should be applied to the article. Further, you can tell the article collapsed because its padding of 2vw is not working. I just wanted to let you know in case you check it out tomorrow and assume I fixed the issue.

Cheers again, man. I really appreciate all your help. It can be hard to find non-obnoxious help on here ;p

Comment: Let me know when you can assist dude, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think the background color is disappearing as a result of you adding the `clearfix` to the `ID`. You could replace `clearfix` with any word, and you get the same result. I think the problem is more likely that once you add `clearfix`, you're adding a second value to the `ID` or, more precisely, [you're adding a space character in the string, which renders the ID invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: The [most updated versions of HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes) also prohibit space characters in `id` values.

Comment: Holy Christ, dude... you're a freaking monster. If I can toss you $20 for helping me out, email me at joeljwarne@icloud.com where I can PayPal you.

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for the offer, but not necessary. Take care.