# How to skip nested <object> tags when using them to have key elements?

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, grid

I have a grid that distributes elements in rows of 4, something like this

```html
<div class="grid">
 <div>el1</div>
 <div>el2</div>
 <div>el3</div>
 <div>el4</div>
 <div>el5</div>
 <div>el6</div>
 <div>el7</div>
 <div>el8</div>
 <div>el9</div>
 <div>el10</div>
 <div>el11</div>
 <div>el12</div>
</div>
```

So I would have a table of 3 rows of 4 elements each one

```css
.grid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(8,auto);
}
```

I create this grid with a `map()` function in `React`, with a function like this

```js
Table.info = () => (
  <>
    <div>el1</div>
    <div>el2</div>
    <div>el3</div>
    <div>el4</div>

    {myarray.map((el, i) => (
      <>
        <div>{el.name}</div>
        <div>{el.name}</div>
        <div>{el.name}</div>
        <div>{el.name}</div>
      </>
    ))}
  </>
)
```

But as expected, I get the warning to include a key
The problem is that to do so I need to use the `<object>` tag, but this tag is seen by `css-grid` destroying the alignment

```js
Table.info = () => (
  <>
    <div>el1</div>
    <div>el2</div>
    <div>el3</div>
    <div>el4</div>

    {myarray.map((el, i) => (
      <object key={'table'+i}>
        <div>{el.name}</div>
        <div>{el.name}</div>
        <div>{el.name}</div>
        <div>{el.name}</div>
      </object >
    ))}
  </>
)
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <div>el1</div>
 <div>el2</div>
 <div>el3</div>
 <div>el4</div>
 <object>
  <div>el5</div>
  <div>el6</div>
  <div>el7</div>
  <div>el8</div>
 </object>
 <object>
  <div>el9</div>
  <div>el10</div>
  <div>el11</div>
  <div>el12</div>
 </object>
</div>
```

So, the question is answered [How to flatten nested divs to display them in a CSS grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535705/how-to-flatten-nested-divs-to-display-them-in-a-css-grid) regarding `css` styling, but is there a way to solve this when constructing the structure with `React`?

### Disclaimer

This question has been marked as duplicated, but the answers there doesn't provide a solution at the React level, which is was I was asking here, yet this has not been reopened

Comment: About the duplication, perhaps there is a solution in the way React works that can be applied here that wasn't provided in the other question, I rephrase the question to emphasize that, otherwise it indeed would be duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I avoided the creation of nested tags by building the html structure with within a string and then injecting that string within a div through `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

That way I could preserve the `css` grid structure and not getting the warning