# Creating a chess board with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have to create a chess board with  `html` and `css` (using `grid`). I created the board and the top and bottom. Now I am stuck with the middle part. I created the size of every field (`80px` x `80px`) My problem is that the individual `field` classes overflow at the bottom of my grid (`chess-board`). How can I fix that problem that all my `divs` "field" stay in my created grid?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chess-board {
  width: 640px;
  height: 720px;
  background-color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: 40px repeat(8, 80px) 40px;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.upper-numbers {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1/9;
  grid-row: 1/1;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  background-color: moccasin;
}

.lower-numbers {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1/9;
  grid-row: 10/10;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  background-color: moccasin;
}

.numbers {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}


/*.main-field {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1/9;
    grid-row: 2/10;
    background-color: white ;
}*/

.field {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}

.field:nth-child(-2n+8) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<main class="chess-board">
  <section class="upper-numbers">
    <div class="numbers">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="main-field">

    <div class="field">a</div>
    <div class="field">b</div>
    <div class="field">c</div>
    <div class="field">d</div>
    <div class="field">e</div>
    <div class="field">f</div>
    <div class="field">g</div>
    <div class="field">h</div>


    <div class="field">i</div>
    <div class="field">j</div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>

    <div class="field">q</div>
    <div class="field">r</div>
    <div class="field">s</div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>

    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>

    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>

    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>

    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>

    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
  </section>

  <section class="lower-numbers">
    <div class="numbers">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you're encountering is that grid properties aren't inherited beyond the children of the container. You're attempting to apply grid properties to great-grand-children, which doesn't work.

In your code, you have this rule creating the grid container:

```
.chess-board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8,80px);
    grid-template-rows: 40px repeat(8,80px) 40px;
 }
```

But this is your HTML:

```
<main class="chess-board">

   <section class="upper-numbers">
     <div class="numbers">
       <div>1</div>
       ...
     </div>
   </section>

   <section class="main-field">
     <div class="field">a</div>
     ...
   </section>

   <section class="lower-numbers">
     <div class="numbers">
       <div>1</div>
       ...
     </div>
   </section>

</main>
```

With `.chess-board` as the container, only `.upper-numbers`, `.main-field` and `.lower-numbers` are grid items and can accept grid commands.

All elements nested inside the grid items don't participate in grid layout. They are standard block layout elements. So they ignore your `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` commands.

My suggestion, if you want to use a single grid container, and until the grid "subgrid" feature is supported by browsers, would be to "flatten" the HTML structure.

Here's a simple example I constructed using a combination of grid and flex layouts.

```css
.chess-board {
  margin: auto;
  width: 640px;
  height: 720px;
  background-color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr 40px;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.upper-numbers,
.lower-numbers {
  display: flex;
  background-color: moccasin;
}

.upper-numbers>div,
.lower-numbers>div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 640px;
}

.field {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.field:nth-child(-2n+8) {
  background-color: black;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 5%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<main class="chess-board">

  <section class="upper-numbers">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </section>

  <section class="main-field">
    <div class="field">a</div>
    <div class="field">b</div>
    <div class="field">c</div>
    <div class="field">d</div>
    <div class="field">e</div>
    <div class="field">f</div>
    <div class="field">g</div>
    <div class="field">h</div>
    <div class="field">i</div>
    <div class="field">j</div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field">q</div>
    <div class="field">r</div>
    <div class="field">s</div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
  </section>

  <section class="lower-numbers">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </section>

</main>
```

More details:

- [Grid properties not working on elements inside grid container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46800525/3597276)
- [Positioning content of grid items in primary container (subgrid feature)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47929369/3597276)
- [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45536537/3597276)

Comment: Hey Michael, thank you so much! I just removed one line in my html and all was running as expected. Thanks again, you made my day!